# How to find the text between two same strings in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to get the name of fields from the Stored Proc which is present between Select and From. But the problem is inside the same procedure if there are multiple select then how to get the fields.
example :

```
IF 1=2 BEGIN

    SELECT Code = NULL, Name = NULL, ItemCount = NULL, SalesAmount = NULL, Quantity = NULL, HeaderID = NULL, Hour = NULL, Operator = NULL, RepTypeName = NULL, TotalSalesAmount = NULL
END;

DECLARE @StartTimeCode VarChar(10), @EndTimeCode VarChar(10);

SELECT @StartTimeCode = StartTimeCode, @EndTimeCode = EndTimeCode
FROM dbo.vDim_Time
WHERE Code = @TimeCode;

SELECT A.ProductCode, A.ProductName, B.DEPTCode, A.GroupCode, A.CatCode, A.Price, A.Size, A.Measure
INTO #MiscProduct
FROM dbo.Dim_Product A
JOIN dbo.dim_Group B ON A.GroupCode = B.GroupCode
WHERE A.StoreCode = @StoreCode
AND A.ProductName LIKE 'MISC %' AND LEN(A.ProductCode) = 6;
```

The code which I have written returns me the name of the fields only from first where Select occurs.  i.e.

Code :

```
protected void GetFieldsAndFormulaFromStoredProcedure(DataTable     pdtUserSelectedStoredProcedure)

    {
         string TempStoredProcedureName = string.Empty,  
         TempStoredProcedureText = string.Empty, FieldName = string.Empty,         FieldFormula=string.Empty;
        List<string> listFields = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in pdtUserSelectedStoredProcedure.Rows)
        {
            TempStoredProcedureName = dr["StoredProcedureName"].ToString();
            TempStoredProcedureText = dr["StoredProcedureText"].ToString();

            if (TempStoredProcedureText.ToLower().Contains("select") && TempStoredProcedureText.ToLower().Contains("from"))
            {
                int pFrom=           TempStoredProcedureText.ToLower().IndexOf("select") + "Select".Length;
                int pTo = TempStoredProcedureText.ToLower().IndexOf("from");
                FieldName = TempStoredProcedureText.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);
                listFields.Add(FieldName);
            }
        }
    }
```

In listFields am only getting field names from below **select** alone.

> SELECT Code = NULL, Name = NULL, ItemCount = NULL, SalesAmount = NULL,
>   Quantity = NULL, HeaderID = NULL, Hour = NULL, Operator = NULL,
>   RepTypeName = NULL, TotalSalesAmount = NULL

How to get rest of field name between Select and From in same procedure. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: *Parsing* SQL can't be solved by simple string manipulations. In fact, using regular expressions would result in much cleaner cod than what you have here, *and* would allow you to easily match true SELECTS, eg `SELECT(?<fiels>.*?)FROM` would match anything between SELECT and FROM in a non-greedy way (ie smallest sequence possible). For such complex text though, you'd probably need a SQL parser

Comment: this is actually a c# question, it has nothing to do with the source of the text. Also, as you can see, the stuff between the `select` keyword and the `from` keyword is not only column names, it's also aliases, it may be functions, sub-queries, etc. If your goal is to parse the sql statement, don't try to re-invent the wheel. there are products out there that can do that job for you better then any code written by any single person.